# Update checkboxGroupInput() choices after file upload

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app below. In this app I want the user to be able to upload his own csv and then automatically this will be added as a choice in the checkbox group below the other dataset "D.B" (which I create in my original app).

```
#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      uiOutput("checkbox"),
      textInput("filename","Set Filename")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    req(input$file1)
 df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  D.B <- reactive({
    #some code that creates the dataset D.B.
  })
  output$checkbox<-renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("datasetSelector","Specify the datasets to compare:", choices = c("D.B")
    )
  })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a reactive value to store choices then add a choice everytime a file is uploaded. Use an observer to watch for file uploads (I also used the library rlist which gives me the append method).

```
library(rlist)

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      uiOutput("checkbox"),
      textInput("filename","Set Filename")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)
#server.r
#fileOptions = list("D.B.")
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    req(input$file1)
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    head(df)
  })
  fileOptions <- reactiveValues(currentOptions=c("D.B."))

  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    fileOptions$currentOptions = list.append(fileOptions$currentOptions, input$file1$datapath)
  })

  D.B <- reactive({
    #some code that creates the dataset D.B.
  })
  output$checkbox<-renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("datasetSelector","Specify the datasets to compare:", choices = fileOptions$currentOptions
  )
  })

}
```

Comment: Clear answer tnx. But if I want also to rename this file how could I do it?is there any way that I could select it from the fileOptions list in order to set its name?

Comment: I will accept your answer and create a new Q for it.